# Objects position incorrectly in view and after device orientation changes

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uiinterfaceorientation

I am creating an iOS application.  It functions within a navigation controller.  In a view I've recently built, the `UITextViews` and `UIImageView` have been displaying incorrectly, at the wrong coordinates.  I believe that this may be due to the `UINavigationBar`.

When I set up the view to mirror that in the Interface Builder, it actually
 displayed the view wrongly.  I again assume that this is due to the `UINavigationBar`.  I managed to "fix" this by altering the Interface Builder coordinates until it displayed correctly.  This is what the Interface Builder now looks like:

I want the view to work in both device orientations (portrait and landscape).  The objects in the view can't easily be told to rotate, so I am positioning the views programmatically.  The code is as follows:

```
-(void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        appInfo.frame = CGRectMake(20, 19, 280, 90);
        updateInfo.frame = CGRectMake(20, 117, 280, 86);
        authorInfo.frame = CGRectMake(20, 229, 172, 200);
        authorImage.frame = CGRectMake(190, 274, 110, 110);
    }
    else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        appInfo.frame = CGRectMake(11, 44, 199, 124);
        updateInfo.frame = CGRectMake(218, 53, 242, 124);
        authorInfo.frame = CGRectMake(11, 180, 340, 90);
        authorImage.frame = CGRectMake(350, 170, 110, 110);
    }
}

-(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [self adjustViewsForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self adjustViewsForOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

**Here is my main problem:**
When the view is rotated to landscape, the objects to not position directly.  They do not follow what is described in the coordinates to be called during rotation.

This problem also occurs when rotated back to portrait:

**How can I resolve this?**  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have any of the automatic layout turned on for this view?  It's possible that you're frame changes are causing the auto layout to become confused.

Comment: No I've turned all of that off, assuming you mean the orientation change settings in Interface Builder

Comment: No, I suspect that he means the autosizing settings in IB.

Comment: I did know to turn the Autoresizing off. My mistake was to turn all of them off. When I adjusted it to the top-left bars on, it worked. Pretty foolish mistake at this point in my development, but thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something complicated using [`sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006893-CH3-SW8) to figure out the size that the various text boxes need to be at the new width to fit the text you want to put in them, but probably easier would be to eliminate the UILabel/UITextView's and the UIImageView, and just create a [`UIWebView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that fills the whole view and use it's [`loadHTMLString:baseURL`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW10) to supply a HTML string that includes your copy and a link to your image in your bundle.

**Update:**

The problem is that you (a) you clearly have autoResizingMasks set; and (b) you're setting your new frames too early (so once the reorientation takes place, the autoResizingMask adjusts them again).

So, a couple of thoughts:

First, you probably have the auto sizing masks turned on in Interface Builder, e.g. something like:

[image: size inspector with auto resizing on]

So, turn off the autoresizing masks:

[image: size inspector with auto resizing off]

Second, while I'm sure you'll do that in IB, FYI you can also turn it  off programmatically:

```
appInfo.autoresizingMask = 0;
updateInfo.autoresizingMask = 0;
authorInfo.autoresizingMask = 0;
authorImage.autoresizingMask = 0;
```

Third, you might want to change the frame coordinates after autoresizing has a chance to screw up your controls. Typically, I'll see guys who defer this sort of frame adjustments to `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` rather than `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` because (a) you have the coordinates of the new orientation (and because navigation controllers are different heights in landscape v portrait, this can be important, though maybe not in your case); and coincidentally (b) you remedy any adjustments that some unintended autoresizing masks may have introduced.

Personally, I've taken to resetting my frames in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` in iOS 5 and later, and in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` and `viewWillAppear` in earlier versions of iOS (I do all of this programmatically in my code). The iOS 5 alternative of `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is superior because it sets the frames right before the rotation animation, and animates the changing of the frames with the rotation animation, which is very, subtle change, but very slick. Once you start noticing apps that do this right, you'll always want to do it that way.

Comment: No the text is no problem.  The `UITextViews` are fine.  The only problem is that nothing is moving to the location where I have instructed it to.

Comment: @DevinGund My original comment was based upon when I have a frame of text and images combined that I want to relayout or reorientation, UIWebView takes care of all of that junk and I don't have to think about it, manually figure out frame sizes, make Objective C coding changes when I happen to want to make changes to my copy, etc. But, if you _really_ want to adjust the control frames programmatically, see my modified answer above.

Comment: @DevinGund Not to beat a dead horse re UIWebView considerations (given you don't want to use one) but the other obvious advantage of UIWebViews is that you can format the text (bold, italics) and include hyperlinks to phone numbers, email addresses, etc. Ok, I'll shutup about UIWebView's now.

Comment: I did know to turn the Autoresizing off.  My mistake was to turn all of them off.  When I adjusted it to the top-left bars on, it worked.  Pretty foolish mistake at this point in my development, but thank you very much.

Comment: @DevinGund if you're more comfortable with your various controls, then you should certainly stick with that. To exactly reproduce what you're doing (two columns if wide, one if narrow) in HTML is non-trivial anyway. But to have text and images that reorient themselves on a screen reorientation is trivial and I frequently do it on things like About screens (one UIWebView and zero coding, plus you get all of the HTML markup and hyperlinks). But hopefully the code above answers your original question.

Comment: So just to make this clear, I would need to make  UIWebview and then redo my view in HTML?

Comment: Yes, theoretically you could replace your four controls with a single UIWebView. Now, maybe because you have your image in the lower left corner, perhaps that doesn't lend itself to the UIWebView, but in general, I tend to use UIWebView for these sorts of about screens, giving me a lot of creative control, not have to worry about orientation changes, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The call to adjustViewsForOrientation: is made too early from the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: call back. Instead, move the call to adjustViewsForOrientation: into the willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration: call back. From the documentation:

```
By the time this method is called, the interfaceOrientation property is already set to the new orientation, and the bounds of the view have been changed. Thus, you can perform any additional layout required by your views in this method.
```

[UIViewController willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
   [self adjustViewsForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments elsewhere, while creating individual controls and moving them around on orientation change can give you a great level of control, simpler approach is to just create a single UIWebView control, and let it take care of taking advantage of reformatting the text for the wider screen. Also, UIWebView makes it easy to format the text (bold, italics) or add hyperlinks (for email addresses and telephone numbers, especially. Anyway, here is an example of creating the HTML string for the UIWebView:

```
- (NSString *)htmlString
{
    NSURL *imgUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"IMG_0999" withExtension:@"PNG"];
    NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

    NSString *htmlBodyTemplate = 
        @"<html>"
        @"<style type=\"text/css\">"
        @"html {"
        @"    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; /* Never autoresize text */"
        @"}"
        @"</style>"
        @"<body style=\"font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:14px;\">"

        @"<p>This application is version %@. The recommended iOS version for running this application is iOS 5.0+. The minimum iOS version is iOS 4.3.</p>"
        @"<p>This application will automatically check for updates at startup. It is recommended to immediately update the app when prompted.</p>"
        @"<img src=\"%@\" style=\"float:right;\" width=\"150px\" />"
        @"<p>This application was created by Ridgefield High School student <strong>Devin Gund</strong> in 2012. He worked with the Ridgefield Public Schools technology department in publishing this application.</p>"

        @"</body>"
        @"</html>";

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:htmlBodyTemplate, version, [imgUrl relativeString]];
}
```

And then, in your viewDidLoad, include a line:

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:[self htmlString] baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll use it in the future